# (elasticsearch) Case insensitive pattern analyzer not working as expected (Solved - user error)

Tags: elasticsearch

I assume I'm making a mistake here somewhere, any help in identifying it would be appreciated.  I have a custom pattern analyzer/tokenizer pair:

(relevant snippet from `_settings` call to my index:

```
   "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "external_id_analyzer" : {
          "tokenizer" : "external_id_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer" : {
        "external_id_tokenizer" : {
          "flags" : "CASE_INSENSITIVE",
          "pattern" : "[,_ -]",
          "type" : "pattern"
        }
      }
    },
```

And this analyzer is applied to a field on the index:

```
    "extId" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "boost" : 10.0,
      "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",
      "analyzer" : "external_id_analyzer"
    }
```

My understanding is that the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag should allow text to be matched w/o case sensitivity, however, when I explain a query, it's clear that the text matched is case sensitive when using this analyzer.

Results for query on "DATA-HIR"

Hit contains `"extId" : "DATA-HIR_2014...",`

Explain details:

```
 "value" : 11.519202,
 "description" : "weight(extId:DATA in 7) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
 ...
 "value" : 25.37294,
 "description" : "weight(extId:HIR in 7) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
```

Querying on "DATA-hir" on the other hand gives the same result, but with much lower score because of the explain plan lacking the "HIR" match...

There is another field with similar data (Just the "DATA-HIR" part of the value) and much lower boost, that uses the default analyzer and the explain plan shows case insensitive matching there.

So clearly the default analyzer is matching case-insensitive, but the pattern analyzer is not.  Any suggestions on what mistake I've made in this process?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm mis-using ```CASE_INSENSITIVE``` as (I think) it applies to the tokenizing of the data rather than the matching...

Answer (score 0):

Or course just spending the time to type it all up and describe it helped me solve it...  I was missing that a custom analyzer needed to specify the type of analyzer as well...  in my case the only changes needed for my custom analyzer were for tokenization, so I just needed to add the "standard" analyzer into my analyzer definition.  E.g.,

```
   "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "external_id_analyzer" : {
          "type" : "standard",
          "tokenizer" : "external_id_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer" : {
        "external_id_tokenizer" : {
          "pattern" : "[,_ -]",
          "type" : "pattern"
        }
      }
    }
```